# How to store redis.get value to a variable

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to store Redis key value to a variable in nodejs, something like

```
let gPost;
redis.get("posts", async function (err, post) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (post) gPost = post;
}
```

but this approach is giving me undefined. Is there any way by which I can store value to Redis? I've already searched for it and a few posts suggested using callbacks. But what I basically want is something like this:

```
router.post("/:id/likes", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        redis.get(`posts.${req.params.id}.likes`, function (err, likeCount) {
            if (err) console.error(err.message);

            redis.get(`posts.${req.params.id}`, async function (err, post) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                if (post) {
                    await customCallback(likeCount, post, req, res);
                    const retPost = JSON.parse(post);
                    return res.send({ retPost, redis: true });
                } else {
                    try {
                        const reqPost = await Post.findById(req.params.id).lean().exec();
                        redis.set(`posts.${req.params.id}`, JSON.stringify(reqPost));
                        await customCallback(likeCount, reqPost, req, res);
                        const retPost = JSON.parse(post);
                        return res.send({ retPost, redis: false });
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log(upPost);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    }
});
```

So, here I want to increase my likes count on a post. But I don't want to hit any unnecessary requests to the database. Here first I'm getting posts.id.likes and inside it, I'm trying to fetch that post. If a post is found I'll increase my likes there only. Else, I'll make an API call to the database to fetch that post. Can you where I'm getting it wrong, or any other efficient approach I can use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of `node-redis`, you can just use promises.

Your code seems to simplify to something like

```
/**
 * Get a post from Redis or the database.
 *
 * If found in the database, caches it in Redis.
 *
 * Returns a pair: post object and whether it was from Redis.
 * @param id Post ID.
 */
async function getPost(id) {
  const redisKey = `posts.${id}`;
  const postData = await redis.get(redisKey);
  if (postData) {
    return [JSON.parse(postData), true];
  }
  const postObj = await Post.findById(id).lean().exec();
  await redis.set(redisKey, JSON.stringify(post));
  return [postObj, false];
}

router.post("/:id/likes", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const [postObj, fromRedis] = await getPost(id);
    const likeCount = await redis.get(`posts.${id}.likes`);
    await customCallback(likeCount, postObj, req, res);
    return res.send({ postObj, redis: fromRedis });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue :)